# Conexão com PDO não dá erro, nem com banco ficticio

Tags: php, pdo

estou começando com PDO.
Estou tentando fazer conexão com o banco e não consigo.

Tenho o seguinte código

```
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "root";
    $dbname = "angularDB";

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=angularDBB"; "root", "root", $opcoes);
        $opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $pdo;
```

Porém, não aparece nenhum erro... Nem se eu colocar um nome de banco fictício!

Comment: Que bom que começou pelo PDO. Remova aquelas linhas com `mysql_*`, adicione isso no construtor. `$opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); new PDO(...., "root", $opcoes);`

Comment: `dbname:angularD` tem aquele `:` mesmo? deveria ser um `=`, `dbname=angularD`

Comment: Telvez (e Eu disse talvez...) o problema esteja na sintaxe tente desta forma $pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname:angularDB', 'root', 'root'
);

Comment: @rray, veja as alterações que eu fiz no código no post... Fiz as mudanças, só inventei um nome para o banco e mesmo assim, nenhum erro é exibido na tela.

Comment: Já experimentaste fazer `debug` ? `var_dump($pdo)`, e vê o que retorna. E isso que estás a usar é uma função ?

Comment: Nem com var_dump($pdo) não aparece nada.

Comment: Passa o script completo, para podermos entender qual é o problema.

Comment: Gustavo, só um exercício: leia só e somente o título desta pergunta, consegue enxergar algum significado? Nem eu... *Please*, dá uma caprichada nisso, custa muito pouco escrever um título descritivo do problema, sendo que "problema com X" é um péssimo título :P

Comment: @brasofilo, só você e o Edilson não entenderam o meu problema. Sendo que descrevo o meu problema no próprio post! Seu comentário foi totalmente desnecessário.

Comment: Nem olhei para seu problema, olhei só pro título. É o ***título*** da sua pergunta que aparece na primeira página. Se quer atrair de primeira a atenção de pessoas com *know-how*, capriche no título, se não, tudo bem, sem problemas. . . . Ah, é, um título descritivo ajuda outras pessoas que estão com o mesmo problema a encontrar a solução.

Comment: sugestão de título: `Conexão com PDO não dá erro, nem com banco ficticio`

Comment: Pronto @brasofilo, alterei o título

Comment: @Edilson, coloquei meu código no git https://github.com/GugaSevero/PDO

Comment: Aí tens a resposta ao teu problema.

Comment: Só esclarecendo, tento atacar problemas de conteúdo, e quanto mais profissional acho que a pessoa é mais direto vou ser; atacar pessoas é trolagem e não é minha praia :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base na *source* que postaste no *[github](https://github.com/GugaSevero/PDO/blob/master/conexao.php)*, neste trecho :

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=angularDBB"; "root", "root", $opcoes);
        $opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

## 1º Primeiro Passo

Primeiro, deve-se mudar a ordem:

```
$opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=angularDBB"; "root", "root", $opcoes);
```

Porque, quando tu crias uma instância do *PDO* na variável `$pdo` ela tenta saber se a variável `$opcoes` está definida, e quais são os seus valores.

## 2º Segundo Passo

Ainda nesta mesma parte do código, temos um erro na escrita dos parâmetros. Onde deveria ser:

```
$pdo = new PDO ('mysql: host= host_name; dbname= db_name;', 'db_user', 'db_pwd', [...]);
```

Está assim :

```
$pdo = new PDO ('mysql: host= host_name; dbname= db_name'; 'db_user', 'db_pwd', [...]);
                                                         ^
```

Existe um `;` em vez de uma vírgula. Remover o `;` seria o suficiente para corrigir esta linha.

Até aqui temos praticamente o problema resolvido, mas agora vamos a análise.

Com as modificações feitas, se fizermos:

```
var_dump(conectar());
// Retorna: object(PDO)#1 (0) { }
```

O que significa que não teve qualquer retorno de objeto, isso porque estamos a tentar saber se retornou algum que não seja *boolean*, pode-se ver isso pelas chavetas.

Agora, se tentarmos imprimir novamente o valor retornado pela função, mas desta vez usando o *echo*, e utilizando o método *cast type* para definir o tipo de retorno esperado:

```
echo((bool)conectar());
// Retorna: 1, equivalente a true
```

Outra observação, é nesta parte do código:

```
print_r($pdo->query('select database()')->fetch());
```

É muito pouco provável que consigamos algum resultado correto com isto, numa tentativa de tentar retornar todos os resultados existentes, porque escrevendo a expressão toda em linha, obtemos um *retorno infinito*, veja neste exemplo, onde usei a tabela `jogos` como base:

```
while($linha = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM jogos")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            echo $linha->nome . "<br/>";    
        }
```

Para além de não mover o ponteiro uma única vez, durante a seleção de resultados no banco de dados, imprime *looping* infinito do primeiro resultado.

O correto seria, primeiro, efetuar a consulta, e só depois retornar os resultados usando o `fetch`, isso se o objetivo fosse retornar todos os resultados na tabela em uso.

```
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM jogos");    
while($linha = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo $linha->nome . "<br/>";    
}
```

Para o caso de um único resultado, como está no teu exemplo original faríamos o seguinte:

```
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM jogos")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->nome;
// fetch(tipo de retorno)
// nome é o indice que queremos retornar
```

A função, completa ficaria assim:

```
function conectar(){
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "root";
    $dbname = "example";
    $erro = "";

    try {
        $opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example", "root", "root", $opcoes);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
        $erro = $e->getMessage();
    }
    if($pdo){
        return $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM jogos")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->nome;
        // Ou usando o looping while, para retornar todos os resultados
        /*
        $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM jogos");    
        while($linha = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
           echo $linha->nome . "<br/>"; 
        }
        */
    } else {
        return $erro;   
    }

}

// Saída dos resultados
echo conectar();
```

Ainda assim, essa função é de longe a melhor prática para instanciar conexões *PDO*, recomendo que procures uma forma mais adequada de o fazer.

---

## Algumas referências:

[How to properly set up a PDO Connection - SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369360/how-to-properly-set-up-a-pdo-connection)

[PDO PHP Class - Culttt](http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/)

[PDO - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: `print_r($pdo->query('select database()')->fetch());` retonar apenas uma linha e não um laço infinito. O exemplo do while na resposta é outro contexto.

Comment: Ah tá bem, erro meu, daqui a pouco edito.

Comment: @Edilson, segui suas dicas, até parte do passo 2.
Coloquei o var_dump(conectar()); e aparecei uma mensagem na tela... Finalmente... O aviso era que o banco não existe. Agora vou colocar o banco certo.

Comment: FECHOU!!!!
object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Comment: Ainda bem, qualquer coisa é só mandar aqui. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 1):

O problema para ser o seu dsn que está incorreto `dbname:angularDB` deveria ser `dbname=angularDB`, o problema é que a falha na conexão não lança um exceção logo nunca será enviada para o bloco catch, mesmo forçando o tratamento de erro como exception.

```
$opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname:angularDB"; "root", "root", $opcoes);
```

Comment: Nada @rray, nem com essas linhas não aparece erro...
Sei que se a conexão estiver OK não aparecerá erro nenhum, mas estou colocando um bdname fictício, pois se der erro é pq a coisa ta funcionando e só terei que ajustar o nome do banco

Comment: E para não acharem que é o problema de versão com meu php hehehee
PHP Version 5.6.7

Comment: @GustavoSevero quando vc tenta rodar algum consulta que erro aparece?

Comment: @GustavoSevero tente fazer isso veja o que acontece, `print_r($pdo->query('select database()')->fetch());`

Comment: Vou colocar meus códigos no git e vou deixar o link aqui.

Comment: @GustavoSevero blz faz isso

Comment: segue o link do git... https://github.com/GugaSevero/PDO

Comment: Estou achando que o problema é no try catch... Não tenho que habilitar o try catch no php?

Comment: @GustavoSevero, algumas vezes o construtor não lança exceção nem erro.

Comment: @GustavoSevero seu código deve ficar assim: http://pastebin.com/NYT0xp5M

Comment: rodei o código que você mandou e não apareceu nada na tela, acredita? To achando muito estranho! Nada funciona!

Comment: @GustavoSevero, se colocar o nome de uma que não existe ele retorna uma exception, se colocar um usuario que não existe tbm. qualquer coisa tente instalar de novo o php xD ou testar em outra maquina. Ta meio estranho